# xcode no certificate real iPhone test lead to APP ID create failure

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Before get Apple developer account, I use Xcode do the no certificate real iPhone test. After get developer account I go to create certificates and APP ID, but APP ID create failure, said bundle id error. I'm sure the bundle id I write is right. Anybody have the same problem？Anyone can tell me how to solve the problem？Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: add com.companyname.appname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hai which mean the apple id already used as bundle identifier for others app or you might be used . Please check it out. i too faced this already... Try with different bundle identifier

Comment: Thanks first. The last part of the bundle id is create by myself, i think can't be used by others.

Comment: ya try the different string . It should work or check it out you might be used it somewhere. If you found it delete and add this it should work Otherwise you don't have it please try the different string. This is my scenario friend.

Comment: Thanks, Probably, I think i need change the bundle id, but does xcode no certificate real iPhone test lead to APP ID create failure?Is that thing exist?

Comment: ohhh cool.. So you get the error code from xcode itself right?